# How to open a form in frame at same page(window) on clicking any link

Tags: html, wordpress

I am working on wordpress and bootstrap.my problem is that on my page there is an image in which I have different social sites link and few page links. Now when the user clicks on inquiry link, I want a form to open on that same page in iframe or div and it should be open only on clicking that link otherwise it will remain hidden. Please help me guys.

Here is my code for header where the image is placed as pearlIcons01.jpg and all the social links and form links are mapped on it.

```
<div id="customHeaderRight" class="span8 hidden-phone" align="right"><img src="http://pearlacademy.com/wp/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/pearlIcons01.jpg" border="0" usemap="#Map" />
  <map name="Map" id="Map">
    <area shape="rect" coords="75,37,93,58" href="http://www.facebook.com/PearlAcademyOfficial" target="_blank" />
    <area shape="rect" coords="100,37,117,57" href="https://twitter.com/Pearl_Academy"  target="_blank"/>
    <area shape="rect" coords="124,36,143,58" href="http://www.youtube.com/PearlAcademyIndia"  target="_blank"/>
 <area shape="rect" coords="73,5,94,21" href="http://xyz/enquiry-form" />
    <area shape="rect" coords="99,6,119,22" href="#" />
    <area shape="rect" coords="125,5,148,22" href="#" />
  </map>
</div>
```

i want to open the form on this link as above:

```
<area shape="rect" coords="73,5,94,21" href="http://xyz/enquiry-form" />
```

help me guys.........

Comment: please guys its urgent.........my boss is gonna kill me

Comment: Just change the target to the name of your iframe...

Comment: @Salketer:  on changing target to my iframe name it will show an iframe and i dont want this i want to show the i frame only if the user click onto any link. and also on passing it to the frame it open the whole page instead of the form.

Comment: Explain it better, where is the form? What's in the iframe if not the form? Ever heard of JSFiddle?

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="customHeaderRight" class="span8 hidden-phone" align="right"><img src="http://pearlacademy.com/wp/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/pearlIcons01.jpg" border="0" usemap="#Map" />
  <map name="Map" id="Map">
    <area shape="rect" coords="75,37,93,58" href="http://www.facebook.com/PearlAcademyOfficial" target="_blank" />
    <area shape="rect" coords="100,37,117,57" href="https://twitter.com/Pearl_Academy"  target="_blank"/>
    <area shape="rect" coords="124,36,143,58" href="http://www.youtube.com/PearlAcademyIndia"  target="_blank"/>
 <area shape="rect" coords="73,5,94,21" href="http://xyz/enquiry-form" target="myIframe" onclick="document.getElementById('theiframe').styles.display='block';"/>
    <area shape="rect" coords="99,6,119,22" href="#" />
    <area shape="rect" coords="125,5,148,22" href="#" />
  </map>
</div>
<iframe style="display:none;" name="myIframe" id="theiframe"></iframe>
```

Comment: yupp heared about that but ur answer is so helpful thnks for this.....but now the problem is that the whole page is opening instead of single form.

Comment: Maybe change the page to just show the form? Or else change the iframe for a div that already has the form in it. And keep the same strategy...

Comment: i m building the form via the wordpress form manager and calling it on a page and then passing the url of that page here

Comment: use a page with an empty template or something? Your question was marked about html... I cannot help with WP.